# resizable background image

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have the following code but my image won't resize, how come? Does the image need to be bigger?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
 <title>blah</title>
 <style type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection">

img#background {     
    position: absolute;     
    top: 0;     
    left: 0;     
    width: 100%     
    height: 100%; 
} 

</style> 
</head>
<body>
<img id="background" src="greenbackground.png" alt="Background Image" />



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `right: 0; bottom: 0;` to the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need this:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img#background {     
    position: absolute;     
    top: 0;     
    left: 0;     
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Note, using css3 you can do this:

```
body{
    background:url(...) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Edit: Missed a ;

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/jJT45/

Comment: Here, try again.. I missed a colon after the width

Answer (score 0):

You're setting it to 100%, but 100% of what? Try giving the body the same 100% height and width properties and see what happens.

Comment: tried it, makes sense. However it didn't work... Any idea of what else is wrong?