# html background size

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a background image that was about 1800 x 1200.  On my computer I have a 24 inch monitor at like 2400+ x 1200 I believe.  The point is on that computer I can see my website just fine.  However I am on my laptop which is only at 1366 x 768 and I have to scroll to the sides in order to see the whole page.  So I decrease the size of my background image to 1200 by 768.  I figured this should work since the laptop is at 1366.  However I still have to scroll.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: A background image won't invoke scrollbars. It would simply get cutoff unless you've specified a width for the body or container.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your background image resizable, so your background will be great on every screen resolution. The solution has been already written here: [resizable background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630075/resizable-background-image)